# In Google App Engine, how do I use reference properties between two entities that reference each other?

Tags: google-app-engine, referenceproperty

If I have two types of models that each reference each other, whichever one I try to define first says it does not recognize the referenced other type (because it is defined further down in the file). For example:

```
class Author(db.Model):
    most_recent_book = db.ReferenceProperty(Book)

class Book(db.Model):
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author)
```

This will claim that the referenced "Book" model is not recognized. If I flip the order, I run into the same issue (except it will say that "Author" is not recognized). How do I get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ReferenceProperty without declaring a type as described in [this article](http://www.appenginetips.com/2008/05/anonymous-refer.html) from AppEngine Tips

Comment: Thanks for the tip adam, I've tried it with ndb and it works perfectly. Do you know if this is the best way? It seems a little hacky...

Comment: Downvoted because the the link is broken, rendering the answer useless :(